# PagedList loses its values because it keeps invoking httpGet method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

I have the following code which shows that I am using **PagedList** to display my search result in a paged order. The problem with it is that at the first result of the search it shows the number of pages related to the search result but once I click on the next page it keeps invoking the method of the page list in the **HttpGet** rather than keeping browsing the result that came from the the **HttpPost** method. How can I fix this

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult SearchResult(int? page)
    {
        var result = from app in db.AllJobModel select app;
        return View(result.ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1,5));
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SearchResult(string searchTitle, string searchLocation, int? page)
    {
           setUpApi(searchTitle, searchLocation);   
         //setUpApi(searchTitle);
         var result = db.AllJobModel.Where(a => a.JobTitle.Contains(searchTitle) && a.locationName.Contains(searchLocation));
        return View(result.ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 5));
    }
```

View :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchResult", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="job-listing-section content-area">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12">
                    <div class="sidebar-right">
                        <!-- Advanced search start -->
                        <div class="widget-4 advanced-search">
                            <form method="GET" class="informeson">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Keywords</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="searchTitle" class="form-control selectpicker search-fields" placeholder="Search Keywords">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Location</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="searchLocation" class="form-control selectpicker search-fields" placeholder="Location">
                                </div>

                                <br>
                                <a class="show-more-options" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#options-content5">
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Date Posted
                                </a>
                                <div id="options-content5" class="collapse">
                                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                                        <input id="checkbox15" type="checkbox">
                                        <label for="checkbox15">
                                            Last Hour
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                                        <input id="checkbox16" type="checkbox">
                                        <label for="checkbox16">
                                            Last 24 Hours
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                                        <input id="checkbox17" type="checkbox">
                                        <label for="checkbox17">
                                            Last 7 Days
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                                        <input id="checkbox18" type="checkbox">
                                        <label for="checkbox18">
                                            Last 30 Days
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <br>
                                </div>



                                <a class="show-more-options" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#options-content">
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Offerd Salary
                                </a>
                                <div id="options-content" class="collapse">
                                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                                        <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox">
                                        <label for="checkbox2">
                                            10k - 20k
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                                        <input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox">
                                        <label for="checkbox3">
                                            20k - 30k
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                                        <input id="checkbox4" type="checkbox">
                                        <label for="checkbox4">
                                            30k - 40k
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                                        <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox">
                                        <label for="checkbox1">
                                            40k - 50k
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                                        <input id="checkbox7" type="checkbox">
                                        <label for="checkbox7">
                                            50k - 60k
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <br>
                                </div>
                                <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-success" />
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-12">
                    <!-- Option bar start -->
                    <div class="option-bar d-none d-xl-block d-lg-block d-md-block d-sm-block">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-7 col-sm-7">
                                <div class="sorting-options2">
                                    <span class="sort">Sort by:</span>
                                    <select class="selectpicker search-fields" name="default-order">
                                        <option>Relevance</option>
                                        <option>Newest</option>
                                        <option>Oldest</option>
                                        <option>Random</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                                <div class="sorting-options">
                                    <a href="#" class="change-view-btn active-view-btn"><i class="fa fa-th-list"></i></a>
                                    <a href="#" class="change-view-btn"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {

                        <div class="job-box">
                            <div class="company-logo">
                                <img src="~/JobImageUploads/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UniqueJobImageName)" alt="logo">
                            </div>
                            <div class="description">
                                <div class="float-left">
                                    <h5 class="title"><a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Home", new { id = item.Id })">@item.JobTitle</a></h5>
                                    <div class="candidate-listing-footer">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><i class="flaticon-work"></i>@Html.DisplayFor(modelIem => item.maximumSalary)</li>
                                            <li><i class="flaticon-time"></i>@Html.DisplayFor(modelIem => item.maximumSalary)</li>
                                            <li><i class="flaticon-pin"></i>@Html.DisplayFor(modelIem => item.locationName)</li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <h6>Deadline: Jan 31, 2019</h6>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        @item.JobDescription
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="div-right">
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "apply-button" })
                                    <a href="#" class="apply-button">Details</a>
                                    <a href="#"><i class="flaticon-heart favourite"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    }


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pagining">
        @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("SearchResult", new
    { page }))
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Is your `page` parameter to GET function is populated with correct value ?

Comment: Yes its with the correct value

Comment: Is your `pageIndex` out of range ? try hardcoding `pageIndex` to `2` and check if that works.

Comment: yes I think index is out of  range the problem is that its keep calling the HttpGet method once I click on the next result even if I try to send parameters to invoke the second action with HttpPost it keeps calling the first method. What do you mean by hardcode

Comment: Are you saying that the page keeps reloading ? Check your dev tools logs.

Comment: the page keeps invoking the next page of the pageList defined in the action httpGet rather than retrieving the next result of the method post

Comment: Ok. Is your `javacript` code invokes the `GET` method ? Please check `Network` tab of `chrome dev tools`. That will tell you the `initiator` or `invoker` of the url. Check if that is a javascript code.

Comment: I have not used any java script code. and the url works fine however it brings different pages from the overall database data rather than the query that has be done for search result

Comment: Did you check the `Network` tab to check who is the initiator for multiple GET URLs ?

Comment: yeah it says other

Answer (score 1):

One solution to preserve browsing results would be to pass searchTitle and searchLocation to your SearchResult GET method as well and keep them in the ViewBag to persist search results on paging.

This is because the PagedList helper uses a Url.Action which invokes the the SearchResults GET request.

EDIT: upon further testing, I would do away with the post method all together and change your form to use the GET method for everything. I have updated the code to reflect this approach.

```
public ActionResult SearchResult(int? page, string searchTitle = null, string searchLocation  = null)
    {


        ViewBag.searchTitle = searchTitle;
        ViewBag.searchLocation = searchLocation;
        ViewBag.page = page;
var result = new List<Job>(); //replace with AllJobModel class
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.searchTitle) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.searchTitle)) 
       {
         setUpApi(searchTitle, searchLocation);   
         //setUpApi(searchTitle);
         result = db.AllJobModel.Where(a => a.JobTitle.Contains(searchTitle) && a.locationName.Contains(searchLocation));
       }
        else
        {
           result = from app in db.AllJobModel select app;
        }  
        return View(result.ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 5));
    }
```

and then in your view, set the values (if any) in the searchTitle and searchLocation text boxes. Also add them to the pagedList helper so the values persist on paging. 
Edit: Also gonna need to add a hidden field to persist the page value on searches.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchResult", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="@ViewBag.page">
    <div class="job-listing-section content-area">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12">
                    <div class="sidebar-right">
                        <!-- Advanced search start -->
                        <div class="widget-4 advanced-search">
                            <form method="GET" class="informeson">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Keywords</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="searchTitle" class="form-control selectpicker search-fields" placeholder="Search Keywords" value="@ViewBag.searchTitle">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Location</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="searchLocation" class="form-control selectpicker search-fields" placeholder="Location" value="@ViewBag.searchLocation">
                                </div>

                                <br>
                                <a class="show-more-options" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#options-content5">
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Date Posted
                                </a>
                                <div id="options-content5" class="collapse">
                                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                                        <input id="checkbox15" type="checkbox">
                                        <label for="checkbox15">
                                            Last Hour
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                                        <input id="checkbox16" type="checkbox">
                                        <label for="checkbox16">
                                            Last 24 Hours
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                                        <input id="checkbox17" type="checkbox">
                                        <label for="checkbox17">
                                            Last 7 Days
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                                        <input id="checkbox18" type="checkbox">
                                        <label for="checkbox18">
                                            Last 30 Days
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <br>
                                </div>



                                <a class="show-more-options" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#options-content">
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Offerd Salary
                                </a>
                                <div id="options-content" class="collapse">
                                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                                        <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox">
                                        <label for="checkbox2">
                                            10k - 20k
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                                        <input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox">
                                        <label for="checkbox3">
                                            20k - 30k
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                                        <input id="checkbox4" type="checkbox">
                                        <label for="checkbox4">
                                            30k - 40k
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                                        <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox">
                                        <label for="checkbox1">
                                            40k - 50k
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                                        <input id="checkbox7" type="checkbox">
                                        <label for="checkbox7">
                                            50k - 60k
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <br>
                                </div>
                                <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-success" />
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-12">
                    <!-- Option bar start -->
                    <div class="option-bar d-none d-xl-block d-lg-block d-md-block d-sm-block">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-7 col-sm-7">
                                <div class="sorting-options2">
                                    <span class="sort">Sort by:</span>
                                    <select class="selectpicker search-fields" name="default-order">
                                        <option>Relevance</option>
                                        <option>Newest</option>
                                        <option>Oldest</option>
                                        <option>Random</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                                <div class="sorting-options">
                                    <a href="#" class="change-view-btn active-view-btn"><i class="fa fa-th-list"></i></a>
                                    <a href="#" class="change-view-btn"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {

                        <div class="job-box">
                            <div class="company-logo">
                                <img src="~/JobImageUploads/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UniqueJobImageName)" alt="logo">
                            </div>
                            <div class="description">
                                <div class="float-left">
                                    <h5 class="title"><a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Home", new { id = item.Id })">@item.JobTitle</a></h5>
                                    <div class="candidate-listing-footer">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><i class="flaticon-work"></i>@Html.DisplayFor(modelIem => item.maximumSalary)</li>
                                            <li><i class="flaticon-time"></i>@Html.DisplayFor(modelIem => item.maximumSalary)</li>
                                            <li><i class="flaticon-pin"></i>@Html.DisplayFor(modelIem => item.locationName)</li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <h6>Deadline: Jan 31, 2019</h6>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        @item.JobDescription
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="div-right">
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "apply-button" })
                                    <a href="#" class="apply-button">Details</a>
                                    <a href="#"><i class="flaticon-heart favourite"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    }


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pagining">
        @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("SearchResult", new
    { page, searchTitle = ViewBag.searchTitle, searchLocation = ViewBag.SearchLocation }))
    </div>
}
```

I know this is a slight change to your original design, so please let me know if you'd like to discuss it further.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: I noticed this code was used in a later question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59988091/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-call-within-it. Please accept it as the answer if it helped solve your issue. Thanks!